# Disable H2O Flow UI

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I'm planning to use H2O with sparkling water (vesion 3.26.0.2) in production.
Thus it is reuired to disable Flow UI that is available via port 54321.
I was unable to find a configuration property to achieve this.

Is it possible or do I have to restrict access via firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no flag to totally disable Flow.

You can either firewall the port or protect it with authentication using one of the various supported approaches.  Hardcoded file username/password  authentication is the easiest (this is called hash authentication in the docs).